# When to use "_type" in Elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

I started reading the documentation about `Elasticsearch`, and I read about `_type` metadata element, in [Elasticsearch documentation](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-definitive-guide/blob/master/030_Data/05_Document.asciidoc):

> Elasticsearch exposes a feature called types which allows you to logically partition data inside of an index. Documents in different types may have different fields, but it is best if they are highly similar.

So my question is: In which situations the best practice is to split documents into types? Because in the documentation, they wrote that the documents in different `_types` should have similar fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a good blog post about type vs index: https://www.elastic.co/blog/index-vs-type

Having the same mappings and fields is a good starting point (since sparsity is an issue). Just be aware that types will be removed in the future, so don't structure your logic around it too heavily. But you will be able to do the same with an enum like field and a filter in your query.

Comment: What do you mean types will be removed in the future? Which version?

Comment: It's a bit complicated and spans mutliple versions, but pretty much with 7.0. See https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/removal-of-types.html#_schedule_for_removal_of_mapping_types for the details

Answer (score 3):

Let's say you create a new index "WWW" and the types of it would be "http" and "https". Both types have the same mapping and fields.  It would be easier to search all the "http" documents like this:

```
GET /WWW/http/_search?pretty
```

and the https like this:

```
GET /WWW/https/_search?pretty
```

It also gives you a logical separation between your data.